# Does passing AnsiString through PAnsiChar (char *) explicitly requires null terminator character or not?

Tags: c++, c, delphi, dll, null

Being new here and to interop and C(++) I did search for an answer on this question but cannot find it on SO or the www. It is my lack in choosing the correct words to search for an answer or I am missing the point of this pretty basic problem...

With interop between Delphi dll and 'C(++) dll caller', do you explicitly state the null terminator character in Delphi dll to pass back to dll caller?

e.g. Dll caller (C-code)

```
char ErrorMessage[10];
(*GetMessageFromDLLFunction)(&ErrorMessage[0], 10); // (char * ErrorMessage, int buffSize)
```

Dll code (Delphi):

```
GetMessageFromDLLFunction(errorMessage: PAnsiChar; buffSize: Integer)

// What if the message generated in this function exceeds 10 characters?
// do I return 9 characters and a null terminator?
tmpMessage := SetLength(tmpMessage, buffSize-1);
tmpMessage := tmpMessage + #0;
System.AnsiStrings.StrCopy(errorMessage,PAnsiChar(tmpMessage));

// or do I return 9 characters without an explicit null terminator?
tmpMessage := SetLength(tmpMessage, buffSize-1);
System.AnsiStrings.StrCopy(errorMessage,PAnsiChar(tmpMessage));
```

What is best/correct practice?

Comment: Not an answer, but the following might be of interest to you in this context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932883/how-to-design-a-c-c-library-to-be-usable-in-many-client-languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you return a string that is sometimes null-terminated, and sometimes not, then you are imposing a heavy complexity burden on the caller. The caller has to, sometimes, add the null-terminator. And the caller faces the awkward situation of having the string in a buffer that is one character too short to contain the null-terminator. It is usually best to push complexity down to as low a level as possible, so my feeling is that, all things being equal, you should always return a null-terminated buffer.

Your code at present makes no attempt to inform the user how large a buffer is needed to store the complete string. You can continue that way but I definitely recommend that you make sure that the returned value is always null-terminated. That would look like this:

```
function GetString(Buffer: PAnsiChar; Len: Integer): Integer;
var
  Value: AnsiString;
begin
  if Len < 1 then
  begin
    Result := STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    exit;
  end;

  Value := ... // get the string to be returned somehow
  StrLCopy(Buffer, PAnsiChar(Value), Len - 1);
  if Length(Value) < Len then
    Result := STATUS_OK
  else
    Result := STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SHORT;
end;
```

Alternatively you can modify the interface to let the caller know how large a buffer is needed. That might look like this:

```
function GetString(Buffer: PAnsiChar; var Len: Integer): Integer;
var
  Value: AnsiString;
begin
  if Len < 0 then
  begin
    Result := STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    exit;
  end;

  Value := ... // get the string to be returned somehow
  if Len > 0 then
    StrLCopy(Buffer, PAnsiChar(Value), Len - 1);
  if Length(Value) < Len then
    Result := STATUS_OK
  else
    Result := STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SHORT;
  Len := Length(Value) + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Why Move and not, well, StrLCopy?

Comment: I don't see it as "cleaner". It looks like premature optimization to me.

Comment: StrLCopy is the standard routine to copy text into a buffer. Move is a much more low level routine, which will byte the user if he or she once moves from Ansi to Unicode. Using the low level Move is an "optimization".

Comment: @0scar Actually the main point of my answer is not the example code but the text in the first paragraph. You asked whether or not your function should always copy a null terminator. My advice is very strongly that it should do so.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis OK, I think it is cleaner with `StrLCopy`. Is the latest version what you had in mind. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes,that is what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

That is entirely up to you to decide.  Since you are passing the buffer length as input, you can go either way.  But if you choose to omit the null in the output, you should have the function return how many characters were actually written into the buffer so the caller knws where to stop reading.  You could even go as far as return an error instead to let the caller know the buffer was too small to receive the full output, if the full message is important.

Comment: In my Delphi function I return a positive integer result when the message gets clipped by the Delphi dll function. No actuel length is returned. So in order to get a correct terminated string in C I manually have to add the #0

Comment: If the buffer is too small or nil, I generally return a positive integer indicating the required size of the buffer. I do not fill the buffer. If the buffer is big enough, I return 0 and fill the buffer with the required text. This way, the user can query the function with a nil buffer to get the required size, allocate the buffer and then call the function again with a properly sized buffer.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That is often fine but it does compel the user to allocate buffers dynamically in order to get some output. If they wish to use statically allocated buffers then it becomes difficult. In other words there are times when truncated text is sufficient.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'd rather document that the buffer must be at least of a certain size (e.g. something like `MAX_PATH` in the Windows API), and make sure that all results fit in such a buffer. I can't think of a situation where truncation makes sense, but there may be such situations. Fact is that it depends on the situation and that there is not one single valid recipe for this.

Comment: @Rudy Truncation might make sense in an API like `GetWindowText`. You might only need to check the first handful of characters to see if they contain a specific program name. Certainly there is no single recipe.

Comment: OK, I agree that for something like `GetWindowText`, in certain situations, not the entire text is required. Then I would also return a zero-terminated truncated text.

Comment: I have to conform to function results the developers of the interface allow me to return. I will clip the text, add a null character and return an error/warning code in the result (it is only allowed to return an error/warning code). Thanks for helping me out.